# Change web.config during deployment

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, web-config, web-config-transform

I need to switch between http and https during development and deployment.

To do that, I need to make the following changes in web.config:

```
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DirectInstallHelperServiceBehavior">
      <!-- need to change to <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"> -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false">
      </serviceMetadata>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
<!-- need to add the following, but don't know how
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
-->
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

So I try to add the following lines in Web.Release.config:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DirectInstallHelperServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" xdt:Transform="setAttribute(httpsGetEnabled, httpGetEnabled)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"></serviceMetadata>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport" xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(/configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding/binding)">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

But I am doing it wrong because when I publish the service to my filesystem, I still see the development http version of web.config.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your `xdt:Transform` value to `SetAttributes`. And remove `xdt:Locator` since there is no name attribute.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"></serviceMetadata>
```

Comment: I made one more mistake by using "setAttributes" instead of "SetAttributes".

Comment: Do you know how to add a block to web.config? I tried InsertAfter...but I think my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I need to use Insert(/configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding/binding) to add child to <binding>.

Comment: Yes. There are some examples on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx.